# Why ANOVA can be used to compare models?

Tags: regression, anova, model-selection, linear

I have seen people use ANOVA to compare models to see if adding additional variables is significant, such as this post:

[Significance of categorical predictor in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60817/significance-of-categorical-predictor-in-logistic-regression)

Why ANOVA can be used to compare models? What assumptions is it based on?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53312/comparing-two-models-using-anova-function-in-r duplicate?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152514/how-to-use-anova-for-two-models-comparison ?